# How to calculate the balls needed to score 50 runs for a team

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, analysis

I have a dataset called todaydel where I have filtered batting_team=='Sunrisers Hyderabad'. I need to calculate the number of balls needed for the team to score 50 runs.

A glimpse of the dataset is as follows:

```
match_idoverballtotal_runs  batting_team
4312    19  1   1   0   Sunrisers Hyderabad
4313    19  1   2   0   Sunrisers Hyderabad
4314    19  1   3   0   Sunrisers Hyderabad
```

I tried using groupby('match_id'), so that we get all the details as per the matches played.

My codes are as follows:

```
todaydel=deliveries[np.logical_or(np.logical_and(deliveries['batting_team']=='Kings XI Punjab',deliveries['bowling_team']=='Sunrisers Hyderabad'),np.logical_and(deliveries['bowling_team']=='Kings XI Punjab',deliveries['batting_team']=='Sunrisers Hyderabad'))]

df= todaydel[['match_id','over','ball','total_runs','batting_team']]
df.groupby('match_id')

SRH= df[df.batting_team=='Sunrisers Hyderabad']
runs_scored = SRH[['ball','total_runs']]
runs_scored.reset_index(inplace=True)

    

index   ball    total_runs
0   4312    1   0
1   4313    2   0
2   4314    3   0
3   4315    4   1
4   4316    5   1

for balls,runs in SRH.iteritems():
    if runs.count()<=50:
        print(balls.count())
```

But this is not helping me. Kindly help me with the approach or any code if possible.
Any similar logic to calculate the number of balls will help. Thanks

Kindly let me know if any inputs required.

Comment: ```total_runs``` is the runs scored on that particular ball, or the total runs scored in the innings?

Comment: Hi Abhinav, total_runs is the tally of the runs scored on each balls.
Like ball 1 is the first ball of the innings, total_runs =0 means no runs scored by the team on that particular ball

Comment: Then you need to calculate the cumulative sum over ```total_runs```; after that find the first ball where cumulative sum >= 50